# Custom apps wont turn on after reboot

Tags: android, ios, swift, xamarin

I have written some basic apps for both iOS (using Swift) and android (using Xamarin). I am often bugged by a problem on both platforms: When I try to run my app from the device (that my IDE installed for me on the device) after a while, it just wont turn on (usually crashes without an error message within the first second of loading). Everything is always fine upon recompiling. With android, this happens usually whenever I haven't recompiled since last reboot. With iOS, it seems pretty independent on reboots, but usually happens within hours, sometimes days.

Why is that? Is there any way to prevent this (Preferably one that wouldn't drastically increase installing time, like posting my app on store or at least creating an installation package and installing it manually)?

Comment: Do you have a paid Apple Developer Program membership?  If not then the provisioning profiles expire after a few days

Comment: On Android, when your app crashes, you can see some useful information in the logs on your device. Try to connect the device to your computer immediately after crash and check "adb logcat".

Comment: Please use Xamarin Diagnostics to get exception.